# Writing a toString method for 2D arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, tostring

I have some code for a 2D array but I don't want spaces at the end of each row before I start a new row. For some reason, I can't find where I'm messing up because a space *is* being put at the end of each row. Basically what I'm trying to do is input a 2D array and the output should make it look the same as the input, except for the {}'s and it'll be a string. For example,

Input:

{1, 2, 3},
{4, 5, 6};

Output:

1 2 3

4 5 6

```
public class Matrix {

// the dimensions of the matrix
private int numRows;
private int numColumns;

// the internal storage for the matrix elements 
private int data[][];

/**
 * @param d - the raw 2D array containing the initial values for the Matrix.
 */
public Matrix(int d[][])
{
    // d.length is the number of 1D arrays in the 2D array
    numRows = d.length; 
    if(numRows == 0)
        numColumns = 0;
    else
        numColumns = d[0].length; // d[0] is the first 1D array
    
    // create a new matrix to hold the data
    data = new int[numRows][numColumns]; 
    
    // copy the data over
    for(int i=0; i < numRows; i++) 
        for(int j=0; j < numColumns; j++)
            data[i][j] = d[i][j];
}

/**
 * Returns a String representation of this Matrix.
 */
@Override // instruct the compiler that we intend for this method to override the superclass' (Object) version
public String toString() {
    
    // TODO: replace the below return statement with the correct code.
    String arrString = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
            arrString += data[i][j] + " ";
        }
        arrString += "\n";
    }
    return arrString;
    
}
```

Comment: You should add some explanation about your code. What is goal for the code, where does it succeed, where does it fail. Don't make us study your code to deduce those points.

Comment: I made the edit. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2):

Next time please post a runnable example.

Your problem was that you *always* added a space after the item, no matter if it was the last one in the line. I now check that with a conditional *+ (j == data[i].length - 1 ? "" : " ");*

**Hint:** It's not good to concatenate Strings. Use StringBuilder for better performance an memory usage. I added a second method *toString2()* to show how it's done.

```
package stackoverflow;

public class Matrix {

    // the dimensions of the matrix
    private final int   numRows;
    private int         numColumns;

    // the internal storage for the matrix elements
    private final int data[][];

    /**
     * @param d - the raw 2D array containing the initial values for the Matrix.
     */
    public Matrix(final int d[][]) {
        // d.length is the number of 1D arrays in the 2D array
        numRows = d.length;
        if (numRows == 0)
            numColumns = 0;
        else
            numColumns = d[0].length; // d[0] is the first 1D array

        // create a new matrix to hold the data
        data = new int[numRows][numColumns];

        // copy the data over
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < numColumns; j++)
                data[i][j] = d[i][j];
    }

    /**
     * Returns a String representation of this Matrix.
     */
    @Override // instruct the compiler that we intend for this method to override the superclass' (Object) version
    public String toString() {

        // TODO: replace the below return statement with the correct code.
        String arrString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
                arrString += data[i][j] + (j == data[i].length - 1 ? "" : " ");
            }
            arrString += "\n";
        }
        return arrString;

    }

    public String toString2() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
                sb.append(data[i][j] + (j == data[i].length - 1 ? "" : " "));
            }
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }



    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final int[][] arr = new int[2][3];
        arr[0][0] = 4;
        arr[0][1] = 6;
        arr[0][2] = 8;
        arr[1][0] = 8;
        arr[1][1] = 16;
        arr[1][2] = 23;
        final Matrix m = new Matrix(arr);
        System.out.println("Matrix:\n" + m);
        System.out.println("Matrix 2:\n" + m.toString2());
    }



}
```

Output:

```
Matrix:
4 6 8
8 16 23

Matrix 2:
4 6 8
8 16 23
```

Comment: (a) I suspect your advice to prefer `StringBuilder` over concatenation via `+` may be no longer true. The implementation of concatenating strings in the OpenJDK codebase has been reworked multiple times over the years. I have read, but not verified, the exact opposite of your advice: "Since Java 9, simple one line concatenation with "+" produces code potentially better than StringBuilder." In my own work, I stopped worrying about this issue, and use whatever is most readable. (b) Otherwise, good Answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by JayC667](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73535404/642706) seems to correctly address your Question.

## Stream, lambda, & method reference

For fun, here is an alternative approach using stream, lambda, and method reference.

Define the array.

```java
int[][] input = { { 1 , 2 , 3 } , { 4 , 5 , 6 } };  // Declaration, initialization.
```

Make a stream where each element is a row, an array of `int` values, from your two-dimensional array.

For each of those rows, each being a `int[]`, make a stream of its `int` primitive values (an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html)), convert each primitive to an [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html) object ([*boxing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxing_(computer_science))), call each `Integer` object’s [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method to generate a piece of text. [Collect](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html) those pieces of text by [joining](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining(java.lang.CharSequence)) them into a longer [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) with a SPACE character as a delimiter.

So we have transformed each row into a `String`. Collect all those strings together, with a LINE FEED character as the delimiter. Then, we are done, with a single `String` object as a result.

All that work, in a single line of code!

```java
String result =
        Arrays
                .stream( input )                         // A series of integer arrays, etc element being a int[]. 
                .map(                                    // Convert each integer array into something else, a `String` object. 
                        ( int[] row ) -> Arrays.stream( row ).boxed().map( Object :: toString ).collect( Collectors.joining( " " ) )
                )
                .collect( Collectors.joining( "\n" ) );  // Join each row of text with the next, using Linefeed as delimiter.
```

Results.

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to return a formatted 2D array based on the anticipated width of the values.

- `%nd` - specifies a field width of `n` digits, right aligned.
- `%-nd` - specifies a field width of `n` digits, left aligned (would have spaces at end of line).
- fields will be filled in with spaces where necessary.

```
public class TwoDtoString {
    
    int[][] mat = { { 11, 222, 3333 }, { 433, 53, 633 }, { 73, 8, 9333 } };
    static String FORMAT = "%5d"; // 5 digit field, right aligned.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TwoDtoString tos = new TwoDtoString();
        System.out.println(tos.toString());
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int[] row : mat) {
            sb.append(FORMAT.formatted(row[0]));
            for (int i = 1; i < row.length; i++) {
                sb.append(FORMAT.formatted(row[i]));
            } 
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }   
}
```

prints

```
   11  222 3333
  433   53  633
   73    8 9333
```